# LINQ: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL snippet within a select statement:

```
CASE 
WHEN wot.id LIKE '%Correct%' THEN 'Corrective'
WHEN wot.id LIKE '%Pred%' THEN 'Preventative'
ELSE 'OTHER'
END
AS worktype
```

which I have translated into LINQ to SQL like this:

```
WorkType = groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Correct") ? "Corrective" : "OTHER" || 
WorkType = groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Pred") ? "Preventative" : "OTHER"
```

If I add one or the other by itself into the select statement, then the query works fine.  However, when I add the OR statement and try to use both statements in the select, I get an "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access" error.

I've seen the other questions about this error and in those cases they rename one of the statements (ex. WorkType, Work_Type) in order to fix the problem.  However, Worktype is the name of my output field so I need to have both be WorkType.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we the entire LINQ query, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution :**

it should be

```
WorkType = groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Correct") ? "Corrective" :
    (groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Pred") ? "Preventative" : "OTHER");
```

**Problem:**

because problem with your code is

```
WorkType = groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Correct") ? "Corrective" : "OTHER" ||  
WorkType = groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Pred") ? "Preventative" : "OTHER"
```

**you are assigning value to worktype two time which is nopt possible**

And even if you write the code like

```
WorkType = (groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Correct") ? "Corrective" : "OTHER") ||  
          ( groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Pred") ? "Preventative" : "OTHER");
```

**this will return boolean value either true or false...**

Comment: I didn't know you could do that.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Keep one `WorkType` and use the second ternary condition as the second expression for the first condition:

```
WorkType = groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Correct") ? "Corrective" : 
           (groupItem.Key.Id.Contains("Pred") ? "Preventative" : "OTHER")
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that.  Thank you very much for your help.